# Access to raw packet data on ESP8266

Tags: wifi, esp8266

The ESP8266 solutions that I have found all seem to try to isolate the programmer from any of the low level network protocols. However I need access to all of the Ethernet, IP, TCP/UDP, etc headers in order to integrate it into another system which has its own TCP/IP stack.

Is it possible to program the ESP8266 to behave as a WiFi version of a simple Ethernet MAC so that it sends and receives the raw 64-1514 bytes of Ethernet data?

If this is possible what would be the best way to go about it? The information available on this device is rather daunting but I imagine it would have to involve using the native SDK or perhaps some variant thereof.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "another system which has its own TCP/IP stack" - you have software that you want to run on the ESP8266 that has its own stack? Why would you want to do that? You'll need to recompile the firmware to omit the stack (LWIP) in that case - otherwise LWIP and your software will both be trying to process IP packets; only one will be able to.

Comment: @romkey Another microcontroller that runs a firmware designed around its own TCP/IP stack. Until now this has been connected to wired Ethernet interfaces using an external PHY IC but the microcontroller has a built in MAC peripheral. I would like to add the ESP8266 to this via its SPI interface to get WiFi connectivity. Other devices are available that do this but they are more expensive.